# How to create a public "start hangout" button without using JS api?

Tags: javascript, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I need to create a new public hangout with my app included. I do not want to use their JS api, so I just redirect user to the following URL:

https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=(my-app-id)

It works great with one exception - the newly created hangout is private and requires invitations. I want to make it "public" - so anyone with the link may join it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule an Event for a date far in the future, set it as a Hangout Event, and get the Hangout URL from your calendar. That Hangout URL can have the gid appended to it, and will be a persistent Hangout URL.

You can [create the event from here](https://plus.google.com/events/create/hangout).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, Adam... I interpreted your question to be asking how to create an ongoing Hangout with Public access at a URL that you could share with others and people can always get into. Did I miss it?

Comment: You got it right, it's just frustrating that they didn't make it as easy as adding some GET parameter to the button URL :)